# Filtering computed list by value in child-list using filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a computed list which needs to be sorted based on a searchstring (if it exists)..

I'm trying to use filter() to sort out this feature, but i'm failing miserably.. Can anyone take a look please ?

**Example Scenario :**
*User searches for "fryseren". this.searchtext = "fryseren". Should filter out the second element in the JSON.*

**Computed property**

```
nluData() {
        return orderby(this.$store.getters.nlujson.filter(item => {
            if (this.searchtext != "") {
                let searchstring = this.searchtext;
                return item.entities.filter(function(sub) {
                    sub.value.toLowerCase() === searchstring.toLowerCase()
                })
            }
            else {
                return item.intent.toLowerCase() === this.selectedIntent.toLowerCase()
            }

        }), ['justCreated', 'intent', 'text'], ['asc', 'asc', 'asc'])

    },
```

**Example JSON (**

```
{
        "id": "fb18eee6-423e-475d-9077-c03dd4ffd80f",
        "text": "Hvor lang holdbarhet har kyllingfilet i fryseren?",
        "intent": "shelf_life",
        "entities": [
            {
                "start": 25,
                "end": 37,
                "value": "kyllingfilet",
                "entity": "ingredient"
            },
            {
                "start": 40,
                "end": 48,
                "value": "fryseren",
                "entity": "ingredient_placement"
            },
            {
                "start": 10,
                "end": 20,
                "value": "holdbarhet",
                "entity": "shelf_life"
            }
        ],
        "isSociety": false
    },
{
        "id": "1072392a-38dc-43f2-affe-74a4fde81bfd",
        "text": "Hvor lang holdbarhet har ribbe i kjøleskapet? ",
        "intent": "shelf_life",
        "entities": [
            {
                "start": 33,
                "end": 44,
                "value": "kjøleskapet",
                "entity": "ingredient_placement"
            },
            {
                "start": 10,
                "end": 20,
                "value": "holdbarhet",
                "entity": "shelf_life"
            },
            {
                "start": 25,
                "end": 30,
                "value": "ribbe",
                "entity": "ingredient"
            }
        ],
        "isSociety": false
    },
```

Comment: What's not working? Also this doesn't seem vue specific, even though you may be using vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner filter function doesn't return anything so it is always false. Add return on this line.

```
return sub.value.toLowerCase() === searchstring.toLowerCase()
```